# Why doesn't a method which would block untill the queue become non-empty?

Tags: java, queue

In the blocking [queue documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) said that the method which examine and block the queue until it becomes non-empty is not applicable. But to me it's not clear why. Couldn't you explain that?

Comment: Do you mean why a method like this could block, or why someone would need a blocking queue?

Comment: You link to `take()`, but your question doesn't seem to be about `take()`. Could you quote the specific part of the documentation you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are misunderstanding that part of the documentation (the table which groups the different methods into four categories) ?

The javadoc is simply saying that the BlockingQueue class has no need for a method which may block (or time out) when it examines the content of the queue, unlike actions such as inserting or removing items into/from the queue, where you may need the options of waiting or timing out if the queue is 'unavailable' at that precise moment.

I don't know exactly why this is, but I can make an educated guess: if you want to look inside a queue, you may get an exception, or you may get a value returned, but then the code will just move on from there -- you can't really block or time out.